# Stop Google Maps from loading location photos/thumbnails

Tags: google-maps

Google Maps automatically shows photos when searching for places, but this uses a lot of data on mobile networks. Is there any way to block the loading of images?

Answer (score 1):

You have to completely disable location features on the Camera else wise it shows the same.
There is nothing like separate `Settings` for disabling this thing in Google Maps.